# Need help. Ubuntu crashes regularly

Tags: crash

I  have a problem with my Ubuntu. This one crashes regularly. It freezes  and the keyboard and mouse are no longer functional. I'm forced to do a  hard reboot every time. Here is the log before the crash. Do you see  anything that could explain the crash?
It's Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS with an AMD Ryzen 1700x and an AMD Radeon rx 480 with 32go of RAM and a SSD of 350 Go + 2XHDD of 2To
Thanks a lot for your help! :)

```
15:06:13 whoopsie: [15:06:13] offline
15:06:03 kernel: usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
15:06:03 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:11:00.3: HC died; cleaning up
15:06:03 NetworkManager: <info>  [1643486763.4463] device (wlx7ca7b0bea15c): state change: activated -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
15:06:03 avahi-daemon: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.9 on wlx7ca7b0bea15c.
15:06:03 wpa_supplicant: wlx7ca7b0bea15c: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:3f:0e:d9:6b:33 reason=0 locally_generated=1
15:05:56 kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:11:00.3: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0005 address=0xd4ab8008 flags=0x0050]
15:05:54 kernel: ---[ end trace db82c9b1b44bee16 ]---
15:05:54 kernel:  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
15:05:54 kernel: R13: ffffffffba25dd40 R14: 000057b7a3f3937a R15: 0000000000000002
15:05:54 kernel: R10: ffff944d7ef6b8a4 R11: ffff944d7ef6b884 R12: ffff944685ab7000
15:05:54 kernel: RBP: ffffb59300157e80 R08: 000057b7a3f3937a R09: 000057bac889af00
15:05:54 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000025b7c068 RDI: 0000000000000000
15:05:54 kernel: RAX: ffff944d7ef6ce80 RBX: 0000000000000002 RCX: 000000000000001f
15:05:54 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb59300157e48 EFLAGS: 00000246
15:05:54 kernel: Code: 3d c1 38 4b 47 e8 14 9a 78 ff 49 89 c6 0f 1f 44 00 00 31 ff e8 e5 a4 78 ff 80 7d d7 00 0f 85 01 01 00 00 fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <45> 85 ff 0f 88 0d 01 00 00 49 63 c7 4c 2b 75 c8 48 8d 14 40 48 8d
15:05:54 kernel: RIP: 0010:cpuidle_enter_state+0xcc/0x360
15:05:54 kernel:  asm_common_interrupt+0x1e/0x40
15:05:54 kernel: Call Trace:
15:05:54 kernel: CR2: 00003f027c667140 CR3: 000000027032c000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
15:05:54 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
15:05:54 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff944d7ef40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
15:05:54 kernel: R13: 00000000fffffffb R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 7fffffffffffffff
15:05:54 kernel: R10: 0000000000707038 R11: 0000000000707188 R12: ffff9446820b3600
15:05:54 kernel: RBP: ffffb593002b0c60 R08: ffff944d7ef589c0 R09: ffffb593002b0960
15:05:54 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000006 RDI: ffff94468004a014
15:05:54 kernel: RAX: ffff9446820b3600 RBX: ffff9446820b35f8 RCX: 0000000000000000
15:05:54 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb593002b0bf0 EFLAGS: 00010082
15:05:54 kernel: Code: f8 49 39 c4 75 ae 45 85 ed 75 1f 48 8b 44 24 38 65 48 33 04 25 28 00 00 00 75 13 48 8d 65 d8 5b 41 5c 41 5d 41 5e 41 5f 5d c3 <0f> 0b eb dd e8 f6 a1 48 00 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48
15:05:54 kernel: RIP: 0010:__domain_flush_pages+0x101/0x110
15:05:54 kernel: Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Default string/AB350-Gaming 3-CF, BIOS F5 02/24/2017
15:05:54 kernel: CPU: 5 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/5 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu
15:05:54 kernel: Modules linked in: usblp binfmt_misc intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi kvm snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel 8821cu(OE) snd_usb_audio snd_hda_core uvcvideo snd_usbmidi_lib aesni_intel snd_hwdep videobuf2_vmalloc snd_seq_midi crypto_simd videobuf2_memops cryptd snd_seq_midi_event videobuf2_v4l2 snd_rawmidi snd_seq videobuf2_common videodev snd_pcm snd_seq_device joydev cfg80211 mc input_leds rapl wmi_bmof k10temp snd_timer snd soundcore ccp mac_hid sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid amdgpu drm_ttm_helper ttm iommu_v2 gpu_sched i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops cec r8169 rc_core ahci gpio_amdpt xhci_pci crc32_pclmul drm realtek i2c_piix4 xhci_pci_renesas libahci wmi gpio_generic
15:05:54 kernel: WARNING: CPU: 5 PID: 0 at drivers/iommu/amd/iommu.c:1260 __domain_flush_pages+0x101/0x110
15:05:54 kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
15:05:54 kernel: AMD-Vi: Command buffer timeout
15:05:50 kernel: ---[ end trace db82c9b1b44bee15 ]---
15:05:50 kernel:  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xc2/0xcb
15:05:50 kernel: R13: ffff944680fa0464 R14: ffffffffba25ddc0 R15: 0000000000000001
15:05:50 kernel: R10: ffff944d7ef6b8a4 R11: ffff944d7ef6b884 R12: 0000000000000001
15:05:50 kernel: RBP: ffffb59300157e18 R08: ffff944680fa0400 R09: 000057b78cbf9f00
15:05:50 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffffffba25dd40 RDI: ffff944680fa0464
15:05:50 kernel: RAX: 0000000000004000 RBX: 0000000000000001 RCX: ffff944d7ef40000
15:05:50 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb59300157e10 EFLAGS: 00000246
15:05:50 kernel: Code: 7b ff ff ff eb bd cc cc cc cc cc cc e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d e6 90 60 00 f4 c3 66 90 e9 07 00 00 00 0f 00 2d d6 90 60 00 fb f4 <c3> cc 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 53 65 8b 15 e7 d5 20 47 0f 1f 44
15:05:50 kernel: RIP: 0010:native_safe_halt+0xe/0x10
15:05:50 kernel:  asm_common_interrupt+0x1e/0x40
15:05:50 kernel: Call Trace:
15:05:50 kernel: CR2: 00003f027c667140 CR3: 000000010fb9e000 CR4: 00000000003506e0
15:05:50 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
15:05:50 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff944d7ef40000(0000) knlGS:00000000
```

Comment: Have you had this problem since you installed Ubuntu? When did the problem start and what changes did you make to your device, software, or configs leading up to the problem's onset?

Comment: Hi, I had this problem before with ElementaryOS and then with Ubuntu. It's my first configuration with this computer (I was on a laptop before), so yeah, I think it's probably some hardware problem.

Comment: So this is a new installation? But you had the same problem with a different distro on a different computer? Did you recently install Ubuntu cleanly or did you reuse the problematic installation that was configured for other hardware? If this is a clean install and you've had the same problem across multiple devices, are you sure that you're running good clean software? If you're using outdated or poorly maintained software, it can crash your system. Are you running a lot of PPA software, or software that you didn't get from official repos?

Comment: Please see my answer. If it helps to resolve the problem, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: my problem with similar issues turned out to be a heating problem, new fan, new thermal compound (arctic silver 5 recommended) fix it after almost 3 years of heartache. these ryzens (I have a 5 and a 7) are hot things.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 2):

**BIOS**

Gigabyte Technology AB350-Gaming 3-CF

**Note**: IO_PAGE_FAULT

You've got a WAY old BIOS F5 from 02/24/2017. Get the much newer version F52e dated 12/13/2021, download it [here](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AB350-Gaming-3-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your make/model motherboard

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS

**Memory**

AMD Ryzen 1700x

Ryzen processors are very fussy about RAM.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

**Radeon**

AMD Radeon RX 480

Update your Radeon drivers by downloading the newest driver from [here for 21.40.1](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-1) or [here for 21.40.2](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-2).